# Binding modifiable rvalue reference to modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, reference, move-semantics, forward, rvalue

I have 3 questions:

1. Can I bind a lvalue directly to a rvalue reference?
2. What happens to the object that being `std::move()`?
3. What's the difference between std::move and `std::forward`?

```
struct myStr{
    int m_i;
};

void foo(myStr&& rs) { }

myStr rValueGene()
{
    return myStr();
}

int main() 
{
    myStr mS= {1};
    foo(rValueGene()); //ok passing in modifiable rvalue to rvalue reference

    // To Question 1:
    //below initilize rvalue reference with modifiable lvalue, should be ok
    //but VS2010 gives a compile error: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from    'myStr' to 'myStr &&' 
    //Is this correct ?
    myStr&& rvalueRef = mS;

    //by using std::move it seems ok, is this the standard way of doing this 
    //to pass a lvalue to rvalue reference
    //myStr&& rvalueRef = std::move(mS);

    // To Question 2:    
    //also what happens to mS object after std::move ?
    //destroyed , undefined ?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1>Can I bind a lvalue directly to a rvalue reference ?

Not without an explicit cast (ie: `std::move`).

> 2>What happens to the object that being std::move() ?

Nothing until it is actually moved. All `std::move` does is return an r-value reference to what you gave it. The actual moving happens in the move constructor/assignment of the type in question.

> 3>What's the difference between std::move and std::forward ?

`std::move` is for moving; `std::forward` is for forwarding. That sounds glib, but that's the idea. If you are intending for an object to be moved, then you use `std::move`. If you are intending for an object to be forwarded, you use `std::forward`.

Forwarding uses specialized semantics that allow conversions between types of references, so that the reference natures are preserved between calls. The specifics of all of this are very... technical.

`std::move` *always* returns a &&. If you give it an l-value reference, it returns an r-value reference. If you give it a value type, it returns an r-value reference to that value. And so forth.

`std::forward` does *not* always return a &&. Syntactically, `std::forward` is just doing a `static_cast<T&&>`. However, because of specialized syntax around casting to && types, this cast does not always return a &&. Yes, that's weird, but it solves the forwarding problem, so nobody cares. That's why it's contained in `std::forward`, rather than having to explicitly do the `static_cast` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1. Yes, the compiler is correct.

Question 2. Nothing happens. `std::move` just casts things to rvalues.

If however you were to use `std::move` to pass `mS` (or `myStr`) to `foo`, then that function might assume that it can "steal" the object and thus `mS` might end up in an unspecified state after the function call.